# Add two values to a VBScript array and compare to see if they equal each other

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, vbscript, equality

What I'm trying to achieve here is getting the two folder size values of `objLibrarySource` and `objLibraryDest` and using an `if` statement to compare the two filesize's and if they equal each other pipe this to the textfile ->
`objFile.WriteLine "Match"`. But my issue is I'm only getting the value for `arrayList(0)` and not `arrayList(1)`

Code:

```
myArray = Array(objLibrarySource, objLibraryDest)
For Each item In myArray
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(item)
    totalSize = objFolder.Size / 1073741824

    arrayList = Array()
    arrayList = AddItem(arrayList, totalSize)
    arrayList = Split(Join(arrayList) & " ")

    objFile.WriteLine objFolder & " File Size: " & Round(totalSize, 2) & " GB"

    If (arrayList(0) = arrayList(1)) Then
        objFile.WriteLine "Match"
    End If
Next
    objFile.WriteLine arrayList(0) & vbCrLf
    objFile.WriteLine arrayList(1)

Function AddItem(arr, val)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = val
    AddItem = arr
End Function
```

Output:

```
D:\LIBRARY_TEST File Size: 7.01 GB
D:\seed_backup\LIBRARY File Size: 7.01 GB
7.01436613406986
```

Comment: Aren't you wrongfully using `Write` instead of `WriteLine` in the last two lines of the main code?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for pointing it out! Updating it did not fix the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had to refactor my code to

```
Dim libsizesrc, libsizedst, libsizesrcSize, libsizedstSize
Set libsizesrc = objFSO.GetFolder(objLibrarySource)
Set libsizedst = objFSO.GetFolder(objLibraryDest)
libsizesrcSize = libsizesrc.Size / 1073741824
libsizedstSize = libsizedst.Size  / 1073741824
objFile.WriteLine libsizesrc & " File Size: " & Round(libsizesrcSize, 2) & " GB"
objFile.WriteLine libsizedst & " File Size: " & Round(libsizedstSize, 2) & " GB"

'Source & Dest SMPDevices Sizes
Dim SMPsizesrc, SMPsizedst, SMPsizesrcSize, SMPsizedstSize
Set SMPsizesrc = objFSO.GetFolder(objSMPDriversSource)
Set SMPsizedst = objFSO.GetFolder(objSMPDriversDest)
SMPsizesrcSize = SMPsizesrc.Size / 1073741824
SMPsizedstSize = SMPsizedst.Size  / 1073741824
objFile.WriteLine SMPsizesrc & " File Size: " & Round(SMPsizesrcSize, 2) & " GB"
objFile.WriteLine SMPsizedst & " File Size: " & Round(SMPsizedstSize, 2) & " GB"

'Library & Source Folder Size Verification
If (libsizesrcSize = libsizedstSize) Then
    objFile.Write "Library Folder FileSize Match!" & vbCrLf
End If

If (SMPsizesrcSize = SMPsizedstSize) Then
    objFile.Write "SMPDrivers Folders FileSize Match!"
End If
```

it work as needed!